# How to pipe downloaded CSV data from Invoke-RestMethod to Import-CSV?

Tags: powershell, csv, read-eval-print-loop, import-csv, invoke-restmethod

How can I [represent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64964864/4531180), or at least view, [this](http://www.bccdc.ca/health-info/diseases-conditions/covid-19/data) data?

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $labs='http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Dashboard_Lab_Information.csv'       
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $labs_csv=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $labs -Headers @{"Content-Type" = "text/csv"}               
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $labs_csv
"Date","Region","New_Tests","Total_Tests","Positivity","Turn_Around"
2020-01-23,"BC",2,2,0,32
2020-01-23,"Fraser",0,0,0,0
2020-01-23,"Interior",0,0,0,0
...
2020-11-19,"Unknown",138,17222,0,37.4
2020-11-19,"Vancouver Coastal",2923,337615,5.12,28.5
2020-11-19,"Vancouver Island",1682,118623,1.4,12.7

PS /home/nicholas>
```

Manually downloading the file, then importing, works [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64964864/4531180).

the apparent parsing error doesn't quite fit, because `Import-CSV` works fine on the file.  Similarly, that the file is "too long" doesn't make sense as the file which was downloaded works fine.

All else being equal, of course.

Perhaps I just need to flip a switch, else powershell will choke on the "large" file?

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod ... |` [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7.1)  `| Foreach-Object { ... } | Export-Csv .\Output.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$labs_csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | Format-Table
```

This, starting with $labs_csv as you stored it, should allow you to at least view the data.  Note that the difference between ConvertFrom-Csv and Import-csv has to do with whether or not the data comes from a file.

You may or may not wish to store your data in a file.