# Object Relational Mapping from CSV with PowerShell?

Tags: sql, powershell, oop, object, orm

"How to iterate through `CSV` data from `PowerShell`?" would perhaps be an alternate question title.

---

This [output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64969211/4531180) is fine:

```
PS /home/nicholas> 
PS /home/nicholas> $flat

Date       Region            New_Tests Total_Tests Positivity Turn_Around
----       ------            --------- ----------- ---------- -----------
2020-01-23 BC                2         2           0          32
2020-01-23 Fraser            0         0           0          0
2020-01-23 Interior          0         0           0          0
2020-01-23 Northern          0         0           0          0
2020-01-23 Unknown           0         0           0          0
2020-01-23 Vancouver Coastal 2         2           0          32
2020-01-23 Vancouver Island  0         0           0          0

..
```

but I'd be more interested in, for example, something like this basic `SQL`:

```
SELECT * FROM $flat limit 3
```

or using `WHERE` clauses.  Perhaps even just returning row/record `n`?  Preferably [represented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64964864/4531180) as:

```
Date        : 2020-11-19
Region      : Vancouver Island
New_Tests   : 1682
Total_Tests : 118623
Positivity  : 1.4
Turn_Around : 12.7
```

Which I take as, [perhaps](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-objects/), the `fields` or `properties` belonging to a generic `Object`.

How do I map a row from `CSV` to an `Object` in `Powershell` on `Linux`?

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't make much sense. You want to return a record that doesn't exist in the data?

Comment: Please try to do some more research and be more specific with your question, see: [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Do you test `Import-Csv` CmdLet :

```
Import-Csv 'your_file.csv' -Delimiter ';'
```

in your case `ConvertFrom-Csv` CmdLet :

```
$labs_csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you a boost with some general concepts in PowerShell, I have tried to give an answer below to each of your specific (sub)question:

> "How to iterate through `CSV` data from `PowerShell`?" would perhaps
> be an alternate question title.

Most [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)s in PowerShell are using the [PowerShell Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines). The [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) is a native object to iterate through each object (row) in the pipeline where [`$_` is the current object](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#_) and `Region` a sample property:

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Foreach-Object { $_.Region }
BC
Fraser
Interior
Northern
Unknown
Vancouver Coastal
Vancouver Island
```

You might also use the [`Foreach`method](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) to iterate through the objects:

```
PS C:\> $Flat.Foreach{ $_.Region }
BC
Fraser
Interior
Northern
Unknown
Vancouver Coastal
Vancouver Island
```

> but I'd be more interested in, for example, something like this basic `SQL`:
> `SELECT * FROM $flat limit 3`

The PowerShell complement of the SQL command `SELECT * FROM $flat limit 3`,
would be the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Select-Object * -First 3

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : BC
New_Tests   : 2
Total_Tests : 2
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 32

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : Fraser
New_Tests   : 0
Total_Tests : 0
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 0

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : Interior
New_Tests   : 0
Total_Tests : 0
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 0
```

> or using `WHERE` clauses.  Perhaps even just returning row/record `n`?

To select a specific object (row) you might use the [`Select-Object -Index <index>` Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object#parameters):

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Select-Object -Index 3

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : Northern
New_Tests   : 0
Total_Tests : 0
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 0
```

Or just directly [index into the object array](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays):

```
PS C:\> $Flat[3]

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : Northern
New_Tests   : 0
Total_Tests : 0
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 0
```

To find an object with a specific property, you might use the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Where-Object Turn_Around -eq 32

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : BC
New_Tests   : 2
Total_Tests : 2
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 32

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : Vancouver Coastal
New_Tests   : 2
Total_Tests : 2
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 32
```

Or the [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where) method:

```
PS C:\> $Flat.Where{ $_.Turn_Around -eq 32 }

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : BC
New_Tests   : 2
Total_Tests : 2
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 32

Date        : 2020-01-23
Region      : Vancouver Coastal
New_Tests   : 2
Total_Tests : 2
Positivity  : 0
Turn_Around : 32
```

To select a specific property (column) you might use the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <property>` parameter:

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Region
BC
Fraser
Interior
Northern
Unknown
Vancouver Coastal
Vancouver Island
```

Or use the [Member Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133329/1701026) feature:

```
PS C:\> $Flat.Region
BC
Fraser
Interior
Northern
Unknown
Vancouver Coastal
Vancouver Island
```

> Preferably [represented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64964864/4531180) as:

Most cmdlets default output the results to the pipeline (see: [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)). If the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console. PowerShell uses default formatters to define how object types are displayed, but you might use format cmdlets, as e.g. [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) and [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list), to format the output to the console your own way:

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Select-Object * -First 3 | Format-Table

Date       Region   New_Tests Total_Tests Positivity Turn_Around
----       ------   --------- ----------- ---------- -----------
2020-01-23 BC       2         2           0          32
2020-01-23 Fraser   0         0           0          0
2020-01-23 Interior 0         0           0          0
```

> Which I take as, [perhaps](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-objects/), the `fields` or `properties` belonging to a generic `Object`.

In PowerShell, they called **Properties** and belong to the specific object.
To list the Properties and and methods of an object you might use the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> $Flat | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Date        NoteProperty string Date=2020-01-23
New_Tests   NoteProperty string New_Tests=2
Positivity  NoteProperty string Positivity=0
Region      NoteProperty string Region=BC
Total_Tests NoteProperty string Total_Tests=2
Turn_Around NoteProperty string Turn_Around=32
```

> How do I map a row from `CSV` to an `Object` in `Powershell` on `Linux`?

```
Import-Csv ./Flat.csv | ... (e.g. Where-Object ... or Select-Object ..) | ...
```

You didn't use the word **Join**, but if you looking for a way to join a list of objects (from a csv file) with another list of objects (resident in PowerShell) based on a related property, you might want to check this external [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026))

Note that [**PowerShell Core**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_7) is based on [**.Net Core**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) framework which are both intended to be *cross-platform*. Meaning there is basically no differents in selecting objects and properties (mapping) between any operating system that supports **PowerShell Core**.

Comment: I have removed the header (with a possible negative approach) from my answer and added a minor remark in the comment of the question.